# How can a HTTP server know the content-length when using transfer encoding chunked?

Tags: http, curl

When I m using both content-length and transfer encoding server is rejecting the request as 400 Bad Request.
Web Server : Nginx

How the server can know the actual file size if chunked encoding is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When data is sent using transfer-encoding chunked, the data is delivered chunk-by-chunk and every chunk is provided with its own individual size.

The receiver of chunked data cannot know the size of the total transfer until the final chunk has been received. Then it has added up the collective sizes of all separate chunks and that is the final size of the transfer.

Sending `Content-Length` together with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is wrong as that provides the size of the body in two places that very well might differ.

Comment: is there a way we can find the content-length when we get chunked request?

Comment: @TomJava: The total size is known once the final terminating chunk has been received. Then you know the full size of the response. There is no way to know the size before that chunk arrives.

Comment: Are you aware of any Apache apr utilities which can give this combined chunk count?